# Listing all recipients from past sent e-mails in Outlook

Tags: email, email-client, microsoft-outlook-2011

I would like to generate a list of all "To:" addressees from my past outgoing e-mails. In a very rough pseudocode, something like this:

```
for all e-mails in "Sent Items":
  add "To:" address to addressee_list
remove duplicates from addressee_list
```

My e-mails are on an Microsoft Exchange server and I use Microsoft Outlook 2011 for Mac. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe there is a way to do it programatically within Outlook. There is one option I can think of, though.

Select all your messages, then from the file menu export them as a text file. Once it's in a text file, you can isolate the lines containing the "To:" addresses with your text editor of choice or, preferably, grep.

Comment: Unfortunately Outlook 2011 doesn't allow saving e-mails as text files. This issue seems to have annoyed many users, and Microsoft hasn't done anything about it yet: http://www.officeformac.com/ms/ProductForums/Office/7748